# How can you find where a specified function is defined in a library?

Tags: python, pytorch, embedding

For example, I am investigating the implementation of `torch.nn.Embedding` class.
I guessed this would be in some file in `nn` directory and found the class in [torch/nn/module/sparse.py](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py#L13).

In this class, `functional.embedding()` function is provoked and I found this function in [torch/nn/functional.py](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/nn/functional.py#L2127).

In this function, `torch.embedding()` is provoked. Now I have totally no idea of where it is defined.

Can you tell me the way to find it, for it doesn't seem that there is `embedding.py` in `torch` directory.

Can you teach me some tips for finding specific function definition?

P.S. I havefound one in [torch/jit/_shape_functions.py](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/jit/_shape_functions.py#458), but not sure at all if this is the one I am looking for.

Comment: Some editor plugins can do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title asks about finding a function definition "in Python".

In code, this is perhaps what you want:

```
import torch
import source

print(inspect.getsourcefile(torch.nn.Embedding))
source, start_line = inspect.getsourcelines(torch.nn.Embedding)
print(start_line, start_line + len(source))
```

Output (for PyTorch 2.0.1):

```
C:\Users\[redacted]\pytorch_test\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\sparse.py
13 224
```

However, most Python IDEs make this a lot easier. For example, if you're using PyCharm, simply holding down `Ctrl` and clicking the name of the class in your code will take you to the definition in the source of the library.

You said a function `functional.embedding()` was 'provoked', I assume you meant to say 'invoked' or 'called'. However, looking at the source, it's not clear what function you are referring to. If you are more specific about the line of code you were looking at, it shouldn't be hard to find - but you'd probably want to share the exact version of the package you're using, a line number, and a copy of the relevant line to be sure.

The tricky part may be resolving the name in context of the namespace where it would be called. This is why it's so much easier to use an IDE for this task, since it does all that for you continuously in the background - it knows what is available at any point in the source, and how a name would be resolved at runtime.

For example:

- looking at `torch.nn.Embedding`, you find lines 13-224 of `sparse.py`
- in that class, in the method `forward()` (which appears to be where you're looking), Torch 2.0.1 calls `embedding()` on `F` on line 162
- that function is to be found on lines 2109-2210 of `functional.py`, where it calls `torch.embedding()` on line 2210 in the `return` statement
- that function is to be found on line 821 of `_VariableFunctions.pyi` - a Python interface definition file.

This is where the trail goes cold - the last reference shows that the actual work is happening outside Python. You'd have to dig into the C++ code for the library to find the source of the function you're looking for.

Comment: They linked right to [the source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/nn/functional.py#L2127) for `functional.embedding`. That function calls another function `torch.embedding`, which they're now trying to find the source code for.

Comment: (And `torch.nn.Embedding` calls `torch.nn.functional.embedding` [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py#L162).)

Comment: @Grismar Thank you for the great answer. As you pointed out, I provided less information than is necessary, and you guessed it all right.
Do some vscode extentions provide the same function as pycharm does? If so, could you recommend one?
Again, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: As it happens, VSCode supports the same shortcut. Hold down the `Ctrl`-key and click the class, function, etc. you want to jump to the definition of. As long as you have your interpreter set up to be one in an environment that has `torch` installed, you should have no trouble.